# c# how to add strings to a list so that they will be accessible from DataSource

Tags: c#, .net

i am doing this:

```
    List<string> list = new List<string>();
    while (myReader.Read())
    {
        reporttime = (string)myReader["reporttime"];
        datapath = (string)myReader["datapath"];

        list.Add(reporttime,datapath);
    }


    chart1.DataSource = list;
```

i am not exactly sure how i should be donig the `list.Add` in order to be able to do the following:

```
chart1.Series["Series1"].XValueMember = "reporttime";
  chart1.Series["Series1"].YValueMembers = "datapath";
```

**question:** how should i be adding the items to the list?

Comment: You'd be better off using a Dictionary object or a DataTable object. Then you can set the value members much more easily, with less code, and it will be immediately understandable to maintenance programmers.

Comment: @david thank you, can u show me how i woul duse the datatable object for this please

Comment: I posted it as an answer. Although I have to say that @Dan Dumitro's answer is just as good.  +1 to @Dan Dumitro for posting the documentation. Either one of our solutions should work.

Comment: @David - Thanks, and +1 for your answer too. @iamagirl - David's solution is even more straight-forward, if you can drop the data reader and directly use a data table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might work simply by doing

```
chart1.DataSource = myReader;
chart1.Series["Series1"].XValueMember = "reporttime";
chart1.Series["Series1"].YValueMembers = "datapath";
chart1.DataBind();
```

, as the documentation says the chart can bind from a data reader:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.chart.datasource.aspx

> The following is a list of objects that you can use as the data source:
>
> DataView
>
> Data readers (SQL, OleDB)
>
> DataSet
>
> DataTable
>
> [...]

Comment: tthanks so much! perhaps u can help with this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4099652/c-how-do-you-return-dataset-from-sqldatareader

Answer (score 2):

There are other good answers, but since your comment asked how to use a DataTable instead I'll post this anyway.  Besides, I don't see how those answers will let you specify the value members, because the code examples I've seen require a named item, and a list of strongs isn't going to do it.  (See @Dan's post).

Instead of using a [DataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz%28VS.71%29.aspx) and using `while(reader.Read())`

use a DataAdapter to fill the datatable.  (Assuming the DB is SQL Server, you'd use a [SQLDataAdapter](http://SqlDataAdapter), but there are different DataAdapters.

```
string connectionstring = "Some connection sting";
string sql = "Select reporttime, datapath from sometable";
System.Data.DataTable t = new System.Data.DataTable();
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter ad = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(sql, connectionstring);
ad.Fill(t);

chart1.DataSource = t;

chart1.Series["Series1"].XValueMember = "reporttime";  
chart1.Series["Series1"].YValueMembers = "datapath";
```

Comment: thank you! could u helpw tiht his one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4099652/c-how-do-you-return-dataset-from-sqldatareader

Answer (score 1):

List.Add is for one item only. To add multiple items, you would want AddRange:

```
list.AddRange(new[] { reporttime,datapath,finalconc,DBinstrument } );
```

However, if you're binding to this, it sounds like you want a list of objects, not strings...so something more like

```
List<object> list = new List<object>();
while (myReader.Read())
{
    reporttime = (string)myReader["reporttime"];
    datapath = (string)myReader["datapath"];

    list.Add(new {
       reporttime = (string)myReader["reporttime"],
       datapath = (string)myReader["datapath"]
       finalconc = "something",
       DBinstrument = "somethingelse?"
    });
}


chart1.DataSource = list;
```

Note, I would suggest in practice creating a business object for this instead of using an anonymous one.